# I got "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable" when trying to write Dice Loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got this error while writing a Dice Loss function.

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d_855/kernel:0', 'conv2d_855/bias:0', 'conv2d_856/kernel:0', 'conv2d_856/bias:0', 'conv2d_857/kernel:0', 'conv2d_857/bias:0', 'conv2d_858/kernel:0', 'conv2d_858/bias:0', 'conv2d_859/kernel:0', 'conv2d_859/bias:0', 'conv2d_860/kernel:0', 'conv2d_860/bias:0', 'conv2d_861/kernel:0', 'conv2d_861/bias:0', 'conv2d_862/kernel:0', 'conv2d_862/bias:0', 'conv2d_863/kernel:0', 'conv2d_863/bias:0', 'conv2d_864/kernel:0', 'conv2d_864/bias:0', 'conv2d_865/kernel:0', 'conv2d_865/bias:0', 'conv2d_866/kernel:0', 'conv2d_866/bias:0', 'conv2d_867/kernel:0', 'conv2d_867/bias:0', 'conv2d_868/kernel:0', 'conv2d_868/bias:0', 'conv2d_869/kernel:0', 'conv2d_869/bias:0', 'conv2d_870/kernel:0', 'conv2d_870/bias:0', 'conv2d_***strong text
```

I notice the error disappears when I set `run_eagerly=True`. Also, notice the error do not appear when I use built in loss function.

My loss function:

```
def compute_metrics(y_true, y_pred):
  '''
  Computes Dice Score.

  Args:
    y_true (tensor) - ground truth label map
    y_pred (tensor) - predicted label map
  '''
  y_pred=tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=3) 
  
  smoothening_factor = 0.00001
  
  rank_4_tensor = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(4, tf.float32))
  for i in range(4):
    
    intersection = tf.reduce_sum(  tf.math.multiply ( tf.cast(   tf.math.equal( y_pred, i ) , tf.int32) , tf.cast( tf.math.equal( y_true, i ) , tf.int32) ))
    y_true_area = tf.reduce_sum (  tf.cast(    tf.math.equal( y_true, i ) , tf.int32    ))
    y_pred_area = tf.reduce_sum (  tf.cast(   tf.math.equal( y_pred, i )  , tf.int32  ))
   
    combined_area =y_true_area+y_pred_area
    
    dice_score =  2 * (( tf.cast(  intersection , tf.float32) + smoothening_factor) / ( tf.cast(  combined_area , tf.float32) + smoothening_factor))
    
    rank_4_tensor[i].assign(dice_score) 
   
    my_out=0
    
    my_out= tf.math.reduce_mean(rank_4_tensor) 
    
  return my_out

def compute_metrics2(y_true, y_pred):  

  return 1-compute_metrics(y_true, y_pred)
```

and the compile and fit:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optim,loss=compute_metrics2,  metrics=["acc"] )# metrics= metrics)
history =model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, validation_steps=valid_steps, 
                    epochs=epochs)
```

Network definition:

```
def down_block(x, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", strides=1):
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(x)
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(c)
    p = keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), (2, 2))(c)
    return c, p

def up_block(x, skip, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", strides=1):
    us = keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    concat = keras.layers.Concatenate()([us, skip])
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(concat)
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(c)
    return c

def bottleneck(x, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", strides=1):
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(x)
    c = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding=padding, strides=strides, activation="relu")(c)
    return c

def UNet():
    f = [16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
    #inputs = keras.layers.Input((image_size, image_size, 3))
    inputs = keras.layers.Input((image_size, image_size, 1))
    
    p0 = inputs
    c1, p1 = down_block(p0, f[0]) #128 -> 64
    c2, p2 = down_block(p1, f[1]) #64 -> 32
    c3, p3 = down_block(p2, f[2]) #32 -> 16
    c4, p4 = down_block(p3, f[3]) #16->8
    
    bn = bottleneck(p4, f[4])
    
    u1 = up_block(bn, c4, f[3]) #8 -> 16
    u2 = up_block(u1, c3, f[2]) #16 -> 32
    u3 = up_block(u2, c2, f[1]) #32 -> 64
    u4 = up_block(u3, c1, f[0]) #64 -> 128
    
    
    outputs = keras.layers.Conv2D(num_class, (1, 1), padding="same", activation="softmax")(u4)
    
    
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model
```

Comment: Your loss implementation is not differentiable, because functions like tf.cast and tf.equal do not have mathematically defined derivatives.

Comment: Thank you .... is there away to fix that? or do you know any implementation for Dice lose that I could use without turning on the eager execution.

Comment: Also, of course what you are saying make sense. But I notice all the example of Lose funcation are using funcation like tf.cast. I wonder why it works in their case.

Comment: You need to be precise, all the implementations of the dice loss I saw do not use tf.cast or tf.equals.

Comment: for exmaple this one from 
https://lars76.github.io/2018/09/27/loss-functions-for-segmentation.html 
def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
  y_pred = tf.math.sigmoid(y_pred)
  numerator = 2 * tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)
  denominator = tf.reduce_sum(y_true + y_pred)

  return 1 - numerator / denominator

Comment: This casts the labels, the problem would be applying any casting to the predictions.

Comment: OK.. Thank you!